# lx-symbols: Python Exception <class 'gdb.MemoryError'> Cannot access memory at address in module

Tags: linux, debugging, module, gdb, kernel

I am trying to debug a module in the kernel.

when I use `lx-symbols`, it shows the [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziAQL.png)

```
(gdb)lx-symbols
loading vmlinux
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/hlleng/linux/imx6ull/100ask_imx6ull-qemu/linux-4.9.88/sc
ripts/gdb/linux/symbols.py",line 163,in invoke
self.load_all_symbols()
File "/home/hlleng/linux/imx6ull/100ask_imx6ull-qemu/linux-4.9.88/sc
ripts/gdb/linux/symbols.py",line 150,in load_all_symbols
[self.load module symbols(module)for module in module list]
File "/home/hlleng/linux/imx6ull/100ask_imx6ull-qemu/linux-4.9.88/sc
ripts/gdb/linux/symbols.py",line 110,in load_module_symbols
module_name module['name'].string()
gdb.MemoryError:Cannot access memory at address 0x7f00040c
Error occurred in Python:Cannot access memory at address 0x7f00040c
(gdb)c
Continuing.
```

```
[root@qemu_imx6ul:/mnt]# cat /proc/modules 
hello_drv_cdev 2631 0 - Live 0x7f000000 (O)
```

It seems it cannot access the module address.

I have already added `nokaslr`:

```
[root@qemu_imx6ul:/mnt]# cat /proc/cmdline 
nokaslr console=ttymxc0,115200 rootfstype=ext4 root=/dev/mmcblk1  rw rootwait init=/sbin/init  loglevel=8
```

Also, breakpoints to a module functions, such 'open', are not worked: GDB doesn't stop on them.

The kernel version is 4.9.88.

Environment is Linux qemu_imx6ul.

I already tried

```
add-auto-load-safe-path vmlinux-gdb.py
```

and it supports `approx lx` now.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem. I had to add to the kernel boot parameters `nokaslr`. After reboot, everything worked fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).